# dotnet core mvc memoryCache.Get returns async response?

Tags: c#, .net-core, memorycache, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I am using .net core MVC 2.1. I amtrying to use ImemoryCache Get method

[image]

I looked at the Get method response and seems its async. 
It returns object and does not allow me to put obj.Result also.

When I see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) 
No where in the sample the response is async.

Why am I getting this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your code (and error message) as *text* rather than as an image. It makes it *much* easier to understand.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is that you've put a task into the cache, rather than putting a value in. But we can't easily tell as you've only shown the fetching code.

Comment: Try "var value" instead of defining it with a type. Might help somewhat in resolving the error.

Comment: @jon Skeet you are correct. I was pushing (Set) wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data in memory is `Task<List<ApplicationConfigurationKeyPairModel>>` but according to your code, you want to get it as `IList<ApplicationConfigurationKeyPairModel>` without convert from Task value to normal value.

So if you want to get it normally without error, you shall do it like this:

```
var allSettings = _memoryCache.TryGetValue(UtilityHelper.APPLICATION_SETTINGS_ALL, out var value);
```

Then you can check what type of `value` is and convert it to list by using `value.Result`.